# Process that toggles other's permission to write to your terminal [Unix] [C]

Tags: c, unix, terminal, tty

I'm working on a process that lets a user allow or disallow others from writing to their terminal. Below is what I have but it does not appear to be working, I'm not sure why. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

main( int ac, char *av[] ){
  struct stat settings;
  int perms;

  if ( fstat(0, &settings) == -1 ){
    perror("Cannot stat stdin");
    exit(0);
  }

  perms = (settings.st_mode & 07777);

  if ( ac == 1 ){
    printf("Other's write is %s\n", (perms & S_IWOTH)?"On":"Off");
    exit(0);
  }

  if ( ac == 2 && av[1][0] == 'n' )
    perms &= ~S_IWOTH;
  else
    perms &= S_IWOTH;
  fchmod(0, perms);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `man 1 mesg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to do

```
perms |= S_IWOTH;
```

rather than

```
perms &= S_IWOTH;
```

`&`'ing with `S_IWOTH` will clear all bits that aren't `S_IWOTH`, and will leave that bit as zero too if it wasn't already set.

You can run `tty(1)` to get the filename of your terminal and run `ls -l` on it to see the permissions by the way, in case you didn't already know that. Don't forget that the group permissions might be important too.

It would be a good idea to check the return value of `fchmod(2)` too.

Comment: Ah right, I totally made a mental not to use a bitwise or instead of an and for the toggle back but I forgot. Thanks man! Also, you wouldn't happen to know how to get there terminal device file of another use from just their username would you?

Comment: @Mikotto: `who | grep <user>` should work. A hacky manual way would be to check file owners in `/dev/pts/`.

Comment: Also notice Alnitak's comment, unless you're just doing it to learn. There's already an util that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Mikotto actually the canonical way to find other users' ttys is via the `utmp` function.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, I ended up just opening utmp and getting a new entry until the input username was equal to the current entry's name and then getting the terminal from that. Thanks though,